# Why can a Map object be created without an apply-method?

Tags: scala, dictionary

```
C:\Users\John>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_32).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.collection.mutable.Map
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

scala> Map()
res4: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing] = Map()
```

When using `Map()` without keyword `new` the `apply` method from the corresponding companion object will be called. But the Scala Documentation does not list an `apply` method for mutable Maps (only an `apply` method to retrieve a value from the map is provided).

Why is the code above still working ?

Comment: Just writing `Map` doesn't call the `apply` method - it just refers to the type. So that `Map` compiles is not surprising. The real question is why it still compiles when you write `Map()`.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a bug in scaladoc. There **is** an `apply` method in object `collection.mutable.Map` (inherited from `GenMapFactory`) but it does not appear in the doc for Map. This problem seems to be fixed in [the doc for upcomping 2.10](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map$).

Note : you must look into the object documentation, not the class one. The method `apply` in the `class` of course works with an existing map instance, and retrieve data from it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an apply() method on the companion object of `scala.collection.immutable.Map()`.  It is inherited from `scala.collection.MapFactory`  .  That method takes a variable number of pair arguments, and is usually used as

```
Map("foo"->3, "bar"->4, "barangus"->5)
```

Calling it with no arguments evidently works as well, but someone brighter than me would have to explain why the type inference engine comes up with `scala.collection.mutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing]`  for it.

Answer (score 1):

As `sepp2k` already mentioned in his comment the symbol `Map` refers to the companion object of `Map`, which gives you access to its single instance. In patter-matching this is often used to identify a message:

```
scala> case object Foo
defined module Foo

scala> def send[A](a: A) = a match { case Foo => "got a Foo" case Map => "got a Map" }
send: [A](a: A)String

scala> send(Map)
res8: String = got a Map

scala> send(Foo)
res9: String = got a Foo
```

If you write `Map()` you will call the `apply` method of object `Map`. Because you did not give any values to insert into the `Map` the compiler can't infer any type, thus it has to use the [bottom type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) - `Nothing` - which is a subtype of every type. It is the only possible type to infer which will not break the type system although there are variances. Would `Nothing` not exist the following code would not compile:

```
scala> Map(1 -> 1) ++ Map()
res10: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)
```

If you take a look to the type signature of `++` which is as follows ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L301))

```
def ++[B1 >: B](xs: GenTraversableOnce[(A, B1)]): Map[A, B1]
```

you will notice the lower-bound type parameter `B1 >: B`. Because `Nothing` is a subtype of everything (and `B` in our case) the compiler can find a `B1` (which is `Int` in our case) and successfully infer a type signature for our Map. This lower-bound is needed because `B` is covariant ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L57)),

```
trait MapLike[A, +B, ...] ...
```

which means that we are not allowed to deliver it as a method parameter (because method parameters are in contravariant position). If the method parameters would not be in contravariant position [Liskov's substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) would no longer kept by the type system. Thus to get the code to compile a new type (here called `B1`) has to be found.

As `Didier Dupont` already pointed out there are some bugs in Scaladoc 2.9, which are solved in 2.10. Not only some missed methods are displayed there but also methods added by an implicit conversion can be displayed ([Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/index.html#scala.Array) for example does display a lot of methods in 2.10 which are not displayed in 2.9).